# Is it possible for the click delay to restart on a new click

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have a list of ZIP codes that will each have a checkbox next to them.  When the user checks or unchecks a ZIP, I'm redrawing a map that has the ZIP polygons drawn onto it.  Instead of telling the map to redraw each and every time a class of "polyZIP" is clicked, I'd like to do a delay where the map is drawn 1 second after the click... but there's the part I'm unsure of.  If the user goes down the list and rapidly checks/unchecks ZIP codes, I'd like each click to restart the 1 second timer so that the map will only be redrawn once the clicking has stopped for at least a second.

I created a (very ugly) test at http://jsfiddle.net/a2f1ydyh/.  You can see on the fiddle that if you rapidly click the go button, eventually the results area will count each and every click.  I'd like it basically that any click would restart the counter.

Here's the ugly code:

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    var timeout = "";
    $(function() {
        $("#go").click(function() {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() { actionFunction(); }, 3000);
        });
    });

    function actionFunction()
    {
        counter++;
        var results = $("#results").html() + "<br />" + counter;
        $("#results").html(results);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
</script>

<input id="go" type="button" value="CLICK ME" /><br /><br />

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like you'd just need to move the `clearTimeout(timeout)` to the beginning of the click function itself.

Comment: I tried moving it to after the timeout = setTimeout... line, but then it didn't work at all... i then moved it it after "actionFunction();" and it worked the same as when it was in the actionFunction function

Comment: Did you try it as the first line of code inside the click handler? Timeout itself should be written a bit shorter by the way : `timeout = setTimeout(actionFunction, 3000);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the timeout before you set the new one in your `click` function.

```js
var counter = 0;
var timeout = "";
$(function() {
  $("#go").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      actionFunction();
    }, 3000);
  });
});

function actionFunction() {
  counter++;
  var results = $("#results").html() + "<br />" + counter;
  $("#results").html(results);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="go" type="button" value="CLICK ME" />
<br />
<br />

<div id="results"></div>
```